# Overlapping text with tables and/or divs

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a blogpost into a forum-format, which i thought would be quite simple with html-tables and some css. I can't attach an image because this is my first question/answer here, but everyone knows the forum/disqus format: two-column with a narrow one on the left for the avatar and a wider one for the text.
Fact is that using just hmtml-css tables, the text floats to the left as soon as it (vertically) passes the image. That is solved by using "position:absolute", but then the whole image&text **overlap** each other AND most or everything that is beneath it, depending on how one resize the window.
Anyway, it's just the old forum-format, what am I doing wrong. Can't link to a page, not a live site yet. I'm using WP with the (modified) Blaskan theme.

Comment: Please clarify your question, make paragraphs, and add code here and/or on jsfiddle.net so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

It is isn't clear if you're trying to add a forum or just a table that looks like a forum-format table.

If you want to a forum in WP, then you might want to follow

- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-forum-to-wordpress
- http://wpmatter.com/top-5-wordpress-forum-plugins/

If you are trying to add a two column table, you'll need to post the html and css using.
For example, you can post like this http://jsfiddle.net/minerva/UJjup/.  You must've added a "position: absolute" in the <td> tag and that is why your text is overlapping

Remove the position:absolute from the  tag.

```
    table td
    {
        position:absolute
    }
```

Then add your css style specifically on the first column and or second column.